# Why performing an histogram equalization by scikit image to a binary image i got a black image after mahotas conversion?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I used histogram equalization and adaptation for erase illumination from the **grayscale images**, but  after the [histogram equalization](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html) (i used scikit image python library) was good, during image conversion in **mahotas** something goes wrong. I got a picture total black. How can i fix it?

- Source image:

[image: Source image]

- Histogram equalization and adaptation;

[image: histogram equalization on an image]

- Result after mahotas conversion.

[image: maho conv]

conversion code from scikit to mahotas:

```
binimg = np.array(img_adapteq, dtype=np.bool)
```

Source code:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pymorph as pm
import mahotas as mh
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage import exposure
def plot_img_and_hist(img, axes, bins=256):
    """Plot an image along with its histogram and cumulative histogram.

    """
    img = img_as_float(img)
    ax_img, ax_hist = axes
    ax_cdf = ax_hist.twinx()

    # Display image
    ax_img.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax_img.set_axis_off()

    # Display histogram
    ax_hist.hist(img.ravel(), bins=bins, histtype='step', color='black')
    ax_hist.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
    ax_hist.set_xlabel('Pixel intensity')
    ax_hist.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax_hist.set_yticks([])

    # Display cumulative distribution
    img_cdf, bins = exposure.cumulative_distribution(img, bins)
    ax_cdf.plot(bins, img_cdf, 'r')
    ax_cdf.set_yticks([])

    return ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf


mhgray = mh.imread(path,0)
binimg = mhgray[:,:,0]
print(type(binimg[0][0]))
thresh = mh.otsu(binimg)
gray =( binimg< thresh)

shape = list(gray.shape)
w = 0
if (shape[0] > shape[1]):
    shape = shape[0]
else:
    shape = shape[1]

if (shape < 100):
    w =  int((shape/100 )*1.5)
elif(shape > 100 and shape <420):
    w =  int((shape/100 )*2.5)
else:
    w = int((shape/100)*4)
disk7 = pm.sedisk(w)

img = binimg

# Contrast stretching
p2 = np.percentile(img, 2)
p98 = np.percentile(img, 98)
img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(p2, p98))

# Equalization
img_eq = exposure.equalize_hist(img)

# Adaptive Equalization
img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img, clip_limit=0.03)

# Display results
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(8, 4))

ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img, axes[:, 0])
ax_img.set_title('Low contrast image')

y_min, y_max = ax_hist.get_ylim()
ax_hist.set_ylabel('Number of pixels')
ax_hist.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, y_max, 5))

ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_rescale, axes[:, 1])
ax_img.set_title('Contrast stretching')

ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_eq, axes[:, 2])
ax_img.set_title('Histogram equalization')

ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_adapteq, axes[:, 3])
ax_img.set_title('Adaptive equalization')

ax_cdf.set_ylabel('Fraction of total intensity')
ax_cdf.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))

# prevent overlap of y-axis labels
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)
plt.show()


plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("after histo")
plt.imshow(img_adapteq)
plt.show()

binimg = np.array(img_adapteq, dtype=np.bool)#uint16

plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("after otsu")
plt.imshow(binimg)
plt.show()

imgbnbin = mh.morph.dilate(binimg, disk7)

#2     
plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("after dilate before close")
plt.imshow(imgbnbin)
plt.show()

imgbnbin = mh.morph.close(imgbnbin, disk7)
#2     
plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("before skeletonize")
plt.imshow(imgbnbin)
plt.show()

imgbnbin = mh.morph.close(imgbnbin, disk7)
out = morphology.skeletonize(imgbnbin>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scikit-image` algorithm probably returns a floating point image with values between 0 and 1.  If you cast that to bool, you'll get all ones.  You probably want

`binimg = img_adapteq > 0.5`

In general, also take note of the `rescale_intensity` function, which will take an image with values between 0 and 1 and return an image with values between 0 and 255.

`from skimage import exposure
image = rescale_intensity(image, out_range=(0, 255))`

Comment: they aren't floating points, i wrote: print(img_adapteq[0]) and was printed: [16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317
 16317 16317 16317 16317 16319 16322 16325 16328 16331 16334 16336 16339
 16342 16345 16348 16351 16353 16356 16359 16362 16365 16368 16370 16373.........
 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 16317 
 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403 16403
 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535]

Comment: Yes, so you have:

`In [7]: np.array(x, dtype=np.bool)
Out[7]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`

Comment: but if you told me to substitute  binimg = np.array(img_adapteq, dtype=np.bool) with   binimg = img_adapteq > 0.5 it does change anything! i get always [ True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True....]. All the numbers are >0.5 and all values are true. Maybe there is something that i don't figure out!

Comment: i think the error is that i give a greyscale image instead of a color image, after conversion in bool i can see the correct image, but after otsu it is again a total black image. Moreover i got this warning:  Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 51
    warnings.warn("This might be a color image. The histogram will be "
UserWarning: This might be a color image. The histogram will be computed on the flattened image. You can instead apply this function to each color channel.

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 107
    "%s to %s" % (dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj))
UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint16

Comment: Please read: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/user_guide/data_types.html

Also, it sounds like you may be sending in color data to the equalization function.  Use ``skimage.color.rgb2gray`` to first convert your data to gray-scale.  You can check if you were successful by looking at the ".shape" parameter of the image--it should be two (not three) dimensional.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I was so stupid! Now i have a new problem, after the good conversion when i use otsu (source code: thresh = mh.otsu(binimg)  gray =( binimg< thresh)   ) some images was transformed quite wrong with many white squares!  Before otsu: http://i.imgur.com/9jnoAHn.png, after otsu: http://i.imgur.com/1wtZciL.png  But i think it's better create a new similar question.

Comment: Please post the source image somewhere, then I'll take a look.